# For loop stops at If condition

Tags: php

Here is a code example that I want to execute in php

```
For ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
{
If($array[$i]=="a")
{
// call a php function
}
elseif($array[$i]=="b")
{
// call a php function
}
elseif($array[$i]=="c")
{
// call a php function
}
.
.
.
.
.
And so on... 
Else
Echo 'Default';
}
```

As soon as the first IF condition is satisfied and the function is executed.. The loop doesn't increment and the php code after this for loop also doesn't execute..

I can't seem to understand why

The same happens if I implement switch case or while statement.. Also I've tried adding break and continue to the end of each if .. But it doesn't make any difference.

Edit: there was small error in the variable part.. But that is the not main issue here.. There are no syntax errors in my code.. Maybe there's some problem with the logic..

Comment: Array contains values a,b,c,....

Comment: Also, what does the function do?
If the function throws and error or contains say die() or exit then the script will not go further than one call to it!

Comment: whats in the called function?

Comment: The function returns an array of values numbers..   which I have to display in each of the IF conditions.. The first IF condition when satisfied is displaying all the numbers as desired but then the code doesn't proceed.. Also the function does not have any die or exit at the end.. Just a 'return'

Comment: @Dagon The function returns an array of numbers that I have to display in each IF condition

Comment: Is there a reason you recalculate the number of elements in the array on each iteration?

Comment: @symcbean I just need to run the loop that many times... Should I use a variable with the number of elements instead?

Comment: @ArminBraun The function has a Return statement at the end which i suppose ends the script, how do I get the values from a function without the return statement?

Answer (score 0):

[Onlne Demo](http://ideone.com/qButof)

You have syntax error in `For ($i=0; $i<count($array); i++)`

correct is `For ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)`
this code worked and have output